# sftp users have full access on linux running vsftpd

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I've setup sftp on my linux server using vsftpd, All the required user permission, owners has been set. But, when I put following in /etc/ssh/sshd_config my ftp connection fails with broken pipe error, if I comment them out, then I can login but have access to complete file system.

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
    Match group group-sftp-only
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Systemlog shows following while user 'ashish' tries to connect.

```
May 23 11:23:00 vm-sftp systemd[1]: Started Session 111 of user ashish.
May 23 11:23:00 vm-sftp systemd[12807]: Reached target Main User Target.
May 23 11:23:00 vm-sftp systemd[12807]: Startup finished in 156ms.
May 23 11:23:00 vm-sftp systemd[1]: session-111.scope: Succeeded.
May 23 11:23:01 vm-sftp systemd[1]: Started Session 113 of user ashish.
May 23 11:23:01 vm-sftp systemd[1]: session-113.scope: Succeeded.
```

Comment: Have you checked for any sftp-related messages in the system logs?